# OpenCV: X and Y angles of a particular pixel knowing both hFOV and vFOV

Tags: opencv, pixel, linear-algebra, angle, camera-calibration

Once that I calibrated my camera and I know horizontal and vertical fields of view (through OpenCV's calibrationMatrixValues function), is it possible to know the X and Y angles (from the center) of a particular pixel?

Suppose I have a camera with fields of view of 100° (h) and 80° (v) and a resolution of 500x400. The angle/pixel ratio is (0.2°, 0.2°). So the central pixel will be (0°, 0°), its left neighbor (-0.2°, 0), the topmost central pixel (0°, +40°) and so on.

Is actually this relation constant through all the image or there is a formula to perform this calculation? Is the obtained information reliable?

This is going to be the first step for triangulating objects in a multi camera environment.

Comment: Are you sure the topmost central pixel will be at elevation +80°? Or will it be 40° so that the bottom is -40° and there is 80° of difference between them?

Comment: The relation you descriped is resonable when the optical axis is vertical to the imaging sensor plane. That means the principal point you got in the calibration is the center of the image, i.e., if the size of your image is [sx, sy], the principal points is [sx / 2. sy / 2]. Otherwise, you have to do some slightly more complex geometry.